# Find element greater than given in partially ordered set

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, partial-ordering

I have a set `S` of elements of type `T`. There is a partial order `<=` on elements of type `T`. It is known, that all elements in `S` are not ordered.
Then, I need a way to perform the following query: *having element `e` of type `T`, find `e'` in `S` such that `e <= e'`*.

Is there a datastructure, that allows to perform such queries efficiently (without linear scan of `S`) ?

Important note: `T` is complete lattice.

Comment: You could use a BST-based set-implementation. At least thats the way how it's done in java ([TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html))

Answer (score 0):

You could preprocess the list and find subset of elements which don't have any other elements greater than those numbers (assume you represented all the numbers as a dag, you should find all the elements that have no parents). Once you have that subset all you need to do is a linear scan on this subset. I don't think you can do better than this.

Additionally, you could also sort this subset by the number of elements each of these elements in the subset are greater than (in decreasing order). And scan the elements in order.